# JSON String passed incorrectly in Twig Template

Tags: php, json, symfony, twig

I have two arrays from my controller that I pass to my twig template. This twig template then passes these values onto my javascript file but how they end up there is incorrect.

```
//Controller

return $app['twig']->render({template_name}, array(
    'cities' => $this->cities,
   ));
```

In my twig template I have the code snippet below:

```
var cities = "{{ cities|json_encode(constant('JSON_PRETTY_PRINT')) }}";
```

I have followed the suggestion made by Sensio's Lab Documentation and this doesn't seem to work for me.

I end up with a json string as shown below:

```
{&quot;B01&quot;:[&quot;Gaborone&quot;]...}
```

Also JSON_PRETTY_PRINT is said to be not defined. If I remove this constant then the error is gone. The most important thing for me is to have the correct json format and I have tried all the suggestions I came through on the net.

Any suggestions on how I can get my json to be outputted correctly?

Comment: JSON_PRETTY_PRINT was added in php5.4, what version are you using?

Comment: On my local development I have 5.3. Whenever I am trying to change my php version on my AMPPS doesn't seem to pick it up I do not know why.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the raw filter, like:

```
var cities = "{{ cities|json_encode(constant('JSON_PRETTY_PRINT'))|raw }}";
```

Comment: Since I cannot php version changed to 5.4 I will rather populate my dropdowns with an ajax call instead as pointed out by @Maerlyn. I will still test your solution at home on my Wamp server though and feedback you on your solution. Thanks.